# What is the best way to import an element dependency?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I was wondering if this is the best way to import html dependancies in polymer-dart.
I want to use `my-other-element` inside `my-element` this way:

my-element.dart:

```
@HtmlImport('my-element.html')
library mypackage.my_element;

import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:web_components/web_components.dart' show HtmlImport;

// HERE I import the dart file
import 'my-other-element.dart'

@PolymerRegister('my-element')
class MyElement extends PolymerElement {
  MyElement.created() : super.created();

}
```

my-element.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

//HERE I import the element html
<link rel="import" href="my-other-element.html">

<dom-module id="my-element">
    <template>
        <my-other-element></my-other-element>
    </template>
    <script type="application/dart" src="my-element.dart"></script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `@HtmlImport(...)` and then only import using Darts `import ...;` directive is the recommended way.

Also:
Using `-` (dash) in Dart file names is discouraged. Prefer `_` (underline)

You also don't need

```
<script type="application/dart" src="my-element.dart"></script>
```

in your `<dom-module>` if you import like suggested above.

Comment: So for if my-other-element is implement the same way as my-element, i would simply import it with `import mypackage.my_element`? or library import?

Comment: `import 'package:my_package/my_element.dart';` or `import 'some_dir/my_element.dart';`